# Why can't I play my video from VideoView?

Tags: java, android, android-videoview

I have gotten very close to getting my video to play, but I am still running into a problem. Here is my code from `MainActivity.java`:

```
public void my_vid(View view){
setContentView(R.layout.my_vid);
        VideoView vid = findViewById(R.id.video_view);
        String vid_path = "/sdcard/Download/Track_horizontal_plane.mp4";
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(vid_path);
        vid.setVideoURI(uri);
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        vid.setMediaController(mediaController);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(vid);

    }
```

Here is my relevant layout:

```
<VideoView
        android:id="@+id/video_view"
        android:layout_width="411dp"
        android:layout_height="667dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

Lastly, here is the error I am getting:

```
2020-12-16 12:40:15.204 25622-25622/com.android.choice D/MediaPlayerNative: getMetadata
2020-12-16 12:40:26.286 25622-25654/com.android.choice E/MediaPlayerNative: error (100, 2)
2020-12-16 12:40:26.287 25622-25622/com.android.choice E/MediaPlayer: Error (100,2)
2020-12-16 12:40:26.287 25622-25622/com.android.choice D/VideoView: Error: 100,2
2020-12-16 12:40:26.302 25622-25654/com.android.choice E/MediaPlayerNative: error (1, -2147479551)
2020-12-16 12:40:26.401 25622-25622/com.android.choice E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147479551)
2020-12-16 12:40:26.401 25622-25622/com.android.choice D/VideoView: Error: 1,-2147479551
```

When I open the content layout containing the VideoView, the MediaController works, and even properly tells me the length of the video I have chosen. As soon as I hit play on the mediacontroller, it tells me the video cannot be played. The file is an `mp4` file, so I would think there should not be an issue. Any idea where I am going wrong? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

1.please make sure that you are parsing URI from an hardcoded string is right one.
it could be better if you try with actual URI. here you can see a sample for getting video from gallery.

```
  fun chooseVideoFromGallery() {
    val intent = Intent()
    intent.type = "video/mp4"
    intent.action = Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
    startActivityForResult(
        Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Video"),
        REQUEST_TAKE_GALLERY_VIDEO
    )
}


override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_GALLERY_VIDEO) {
            val uri: Uri? = data!!.data
         
        }
    } 
}
```

2.if the issue is not with URI then it could be better if you use Exo player(build by google) instead of video player so that will support wide range of video and audio container.